# How to read value from unknown type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use `DatoCMS` to render articles on my `React` website. I would like to render structured text so I use `StructuredText` component which comes from `DatoCMS api`.

But, I try read a value to render responsive image, I get error.

Here's my code:

```
  <StructuredText
      data={isFull ? content : null}
      renderBlock={({ record }) => {
        if (record.__typename === 'MyblockRecord' && isFull) {
          return (
            <div style={{ width: '80%', margin: '20px auto' }}>
              <Image data={record.image.responsiveImage} /> /*here i get error 'Object is of type 'unknown'*/
            </div>
          ); 
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }}
    />
```

I can't read `record.image.responsiveImage` because record has `Record` type:

```js
export declare type Record = {
    __typename: string;
    id: string;
} & {
    [prop: string]: unknown;
};
```

How can I read value `image.responsiveImage`?

Answer (score 2):

For `unknown` types you can cast to the `any` type before accessing sub-properties.

For your case, you can use:

```
let responsiveImage = (record.image as any).responsiveImage;
```

Or in context:

```
<Image data={(record.image as any).responsiveImage} />
```

If you want more strict usage of type checking you should do something like this:

1. Define an interface for `MyBlockRecord` that extends `Record`

```
interface MyBlockRecord extends Record {
  __typename: 'MyblockRecord',
  image: {
    responsiveImage: any;
  }
}
```

2. Define an identity function for `MyBlockRecord`

```
function isMyBlockRecord(o: any): o is MyBlockRecord {
  return o.__typename === 'MyblockRecord';
}
```

3. Ensure a given object passes the identity check before accessing properties specific to the extended interface:

```
if (isMyBlockRecord(record)) {
  record.image.responsiveImage;
}
```

When you check the type using an identity function, you don't have to cast to `any` and your code is more type safe.

In context this would be:

```
<StructuredText
  data={isFull ? content : null}
  renderBlock={({ record }) => {
   if (isFull && isMyBlockRecord(record)) {
     return (
       <div style={{ width: '80%', margin: '20px auto' }}>
         <Image data={record.image.responsiveImage} />
       </div>
     ); 
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }}
/>
```

One more note is that since TypeScript has built in `Record` type, I would recommend calling the `Record` type in your code something else (if not from a third-party library) to avoid conflict and confusion.

Answer (score 1):

[@eskimwier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3456751/eskimwier)'s answer works perfectly. But if like me you have the [no-explicit-any ESLint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.29.2/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) in place to warn against using `any` as a type you can use the `ResponsiveImageType` from the `react-datocms` package.

```
import { ResponsiveImageType } from 'react-datocms';

type RecordImageType = {
  responsiveImage: ResponsiveImageType;
};


<Image data={(record.image as RecordImageType).responsiveImage} />
```